# SQL error foreign key constraint

Tags: symfony1

I'm struggling for four days days now with an sql foreign key constraint fails and I reaaly have no idea why. I've read all I could about that subject and it seems that everything is fine.

Here is my schema.yml

```
Soiree:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
  titre:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  description:  { type: blob(), notnull: true }
  adresse: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  code_postal: {type: integer, notnull: true }
  ville: {type: string(255), notnull:true}
  date: {type: timestamp, notnull: true }
  type_id: {type: integer, notnull: true }
  flyer: {type: string(255), notnull:true }
  is_visible: { type: boolean, notnull:true, default:0 }
  user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
relations:
  sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users} 
  Type: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: type_id, foreign: id, alias: Types, class: Type, refClass: Soiree}  

Type:
  columns:
    titre: {type: string(255), notnull: true}

Invitation:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    titre:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description:  { type: blob(), notnull: true }
    image:      { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    is_sent: {type: boolean, notnull:true, default:0}
    adresse:         { type: string(255) }
    code_postal:          { type: string(255) }
    code_QR: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    invites_id: {type:integer }
    user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
    groupe_invites_id : {type:integer, notnull: true }
    soiree_id: {type:integer, notnull:true}
  relations:
    Invites: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: invites_id, foreign: id, alias: invite, class: Invites, refClass: Invitation } 
    Groupe_invites: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: groupe_invites_id, foreign: id, alias: invit_groupes, class: Groupe_invites, refClass: Invitation } 
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users} 
    Soiree: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: soiree_id, foreign: id, alias :Soirees, class: Soiree, refClass: Invitation } 



Groupe_invites:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    titre:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description:     { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    invites_id:     { type: integer, notnull: true }
    soiree_id: { type: integer }
    user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
  relations:
    Invites:
      onDelete: CASCADE
      local: invites_id
      foreign: id
      alias: invites
      class: Invites
      refClass: Groupe_invites
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users} 
    Soiree: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: soiree_id, foreign: id, alias: Soiree, class: Soiree, refClass: Groupe_invites } 

Invites:
  columns:
    nom:  { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    prenom: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    age: {type: integer, notnull : true }
    email: {type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    adresse: {type: blob(), notnull: true }
    telephone: {type: integer(255), notnull: true }
    soiree_id: {type: integer, notnull: true }
    user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
  relations:
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users} 
    Soiree: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: soiree_id, foreign: id, alias: Soiree_invite, class: Soiree, refClass: Invites } 

Organisateur:
   actAs: {Timestampable: ~ }
   columns:
    nom: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    prenom: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    age: {type: integer, notnull: true }
    description: {type: blob(), notnull: true }
    photo: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
  relations:
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users} 


Image:
columns:
    titre: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    lien: {type: string(255)}
    album_id: {type: integer}
    user_id: {type: integer}
relations:
    Album: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: album_id, foreign: id, alias: Albums, class:Album, refClass:Image}
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id} 


Album:
columns:
    titre: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description: {type: blob(), notnull: true }
    user_id: {type:integer, notnull: true}
relations:
    sfGuardUser: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id}
```

And I have an error of type:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`soiree`.`invitation`, CONSTRAINT `invitation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`invites_id`) REFERENCES `invitation` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

I really need help on this one, thank you !

Comment: Does this error message occur when you're trying to upload fixtures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically add the id column to my tables.  Apply this to the tables where it makes sense:

id:         { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }

Comment: Hi and first of all thank you for taking the time to read and answer my post. Unfortunatly I made the changes you told me to do and nothing has changed, i still get the same error...

Comment: make sure any table you have a foreign:id reference has an id in that table.  for example on the Groupe_Invites table:  Soiree: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: soiree_id, foreign: id, alias: Soiree, class: Soiree, refClass: Groupe_invites }  make sure that the Soriee table has an id since you're trying to reference it via foreign:id